# ValueError в функции max

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np

A=np.array([[6,1,5],[-1,6,1],[1,2,5]])

X=[1,1,1]

lambd=[0,1]
eps=0.0001
i=0
while(abs(lambd[i+1]-lambd[i])>eps):
    i+=1
    copyX=X
    X=A*X
    lam=[]
    for j in range(3):
        lam.append(X[j]/copyX[j])
    lambd.append(max(lam))
print(lambd)
```

Когда пытаюсь добавить в список `lambd` наибольший элемент списка `lam`, используя функцию `max`, ловится ошибка ValueError.

Answer (score 1):

А что вы хотите найти через функцию `max` в списке массивов о которых `max` похоже не очень знает

```
lambd.append(max(lam))
```

Может вам надо использовать

```
lambd.append(np.max(lam))
```